# guardar archivo con JFileChooser

Tags: java, java-swing, archivo, java-8

tengo una duda acerca de como puedo hacer que el usuario escoja donde quiere guardar el archivo que descargó de una base de datos. Aqui les paso el código en donde a través del nombre con el que se guardó el archivo en la base de datos se descarga dicho archivo, pero se guarda en la carpeta del proyecto y yo quiero que se escoja donde se quiere guardar el archivo con el JFileChooser`

```
public void descargarArchivoSql(){

Conexion con = new Conexion();

Connection st = con.conectate();

try {
    Statement execute = st.createStatement();
    String nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ponga el nombre del archivo");
    ResultSet rs = execute.executeQuery("SELECT * from archivos where nombre = '"+nombre+"'");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Archivo descargandose con exito2");
    while(rs.next()){
        nombreArchivo=rs.getString("nombre");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nombre del archivo"+ nombreArchivo);
        extension= FilenameUtils.getExtension(nombreArchivo);
    Blob blob=rs.getBlob("archivo");
    InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();        
        guardarArchivoDd(is, nombre);           
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la base de datos"+ e); 
}
}

//Guardar Archivo en el equipo
public void guardarArchivoDd(InputStream x,String nombre) throws 
              FileNotFoundException, IOException{

File fichero = new File(nombre+"."+extension);    
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(x);
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new  
FileOutputStream(fichero));     
byte[] bytes = new byte[858993459];      
int len = 0;   
while((len = in.read(bytes))>0){  
out.write(bytes,0,len);      
}     
out.flush();      
out.close();    
in.close();
}`
```

Comment: Podes usar JFileChooser en modo folder para seleccionar donde guardar archivo:

 JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            int option = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
            if(option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
 File folder = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();}

Answer (score 0):

Con este algoritmo puedes guardar archivos en la dirección de interés.

```
public void guardarArchivo(){ System.out.println("Ejecutando");
    JFileChooser seleccion = new JFileChooser(); // Se crea la instancia para colocar parametros de interes
    seleccion.setDialogTitle("GUARDAR");    // Titulo de la ventana emergente
    seleccion.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG); // El tipo de JFileChooser que vamos a usar
    seleccion.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Handwriting", 0, 18)); // (opcional) Cambiando el tipo de letra
    //seleccion.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY); //(opcional) Estableciendo que solo me muestre los directorios. 

    int respuesta = seleccion.showSaveDialog(this); // Se apertura la ventana.
    switch(respuesta){ // segun la opcion del usuario se ejecutan los algoritmos de interes
        case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
          System.out.println("Guardar");
          break;
        case JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION:
          System.out.println("Cancelado");
          break;
        default :
          System.out.println("Error");
          break;
    }
}
```